# Vertical text with responsiveness

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I am struggling with the vertical text

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0Ybq5brtSJrrbASTNIUU?p=preview)

What i am trying to do is making a vertical text where:

1. If a short text comes inside the div of vertical text then it should be in the middle of the div
2. If long text is comes inside the div it should be started from bottom of the page but it should be responsive (for example if i minimize my window bottom text should not hide it will go up in the div) and `...` ellipses should be there at the last of the large text in vertical text

I have achieved 1. But 2nd is not completely working, there is no responsiveness and text is going inside the div and not visible.

Comment: This does not make sense.

Comment: thanks for your time :)

Comment: What does it mean " If a large text comes in the div"?

Comment: please see my plunker you will get it

Comment: I did but i dont get it.

Comment: " If a large text comes in the div"? this is not in my question what i am asking is if the large text is inside the div container the it overflows it at the bottom and hide in it.

Comment: Please define what "large text" is.

Comment: Maybe it's a long text?

Comment: If a text is less than x characters do 1. If a text is more than x characters do 2. Honestly not that hard to understand.

Comment: yes but how can i do it in css?

Comment: and what about responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```css
.main{
 transform: translate(0, 50%) rotate(-90deg);
  
}
.sub{
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 250px; 
    height:20px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;   
    text-align:center;       
    position: absolute;  
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid grey;   
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white, lightgrey);
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.two{
  top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="sub one">Hello world!</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub two">a large text too large to contain tin the div. large text too large to contain tin the div.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: classes should be same.. can we achieve it through it?

Comment: if classes are same it will overlay each other